# error: "__forceinline__" redefined in simple program

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Compiling the 3-line program `test-cuda.cpp`

```
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

int main() { return 0; }
```

results in a compiler warning/error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 test-cuda.cpp -I/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include -Werror
In file included from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:147,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/detail/detect_cuda_runtime.cuh:38,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_arch.cuh:41,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cub/util_debug.cuh:40,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/config.h:43,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/system/cuda/detail/execution_policy.h:35,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/iterator/detail/device_system_tag.h:23,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/iterator/iterator_traits.h:62,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/type_traits/pointer_traits.h:23,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/raw_pointer_cast.h:20,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/execute_with_allocator.h:23,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/execution_policy.h:25,
                 from test-cuda.cpp:1:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/crt/host_defines.h:86: error: "__forceinline__" redefined [-Werror]
   86 | #define __forceinline__ \
      | 
In file included from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/version:13,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/cstddef:20,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/type_traits:17,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/type_traits.h:27,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/execute_with_allocator_fwd.h:21,
                 from /opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/thrust/detail/execute_with_allocator.h:21:
/opt/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda/std/detail/__config:38: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   38 |         #define __forceinline__
      | 
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

This is a stripped down version of an issue we're facing in a larger project in which we compile w/ `-Werror`.

Is there something we're missing, or a workaround without having to change the CUDA/thrust source code?

Similar warning occurs compiling w/ `nvcc -std=c++17 test-cuda.cpp`.

OS: arch linux

Cuda: 12.1.0

GCC: 12.2.1

Comment: According to lines 38-40 in [this link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/blob/main/include/cuda/std/detail/__config), that should not be happening.

Comment: I don't have any trouble with `nvcc` when compiling it as a `.cu` file.  That is my usual suggestion with thrust.

Comment: Don’t use g++ to compile thrust code. Use nvcc

Comment: @PaulSanders That's where it is first defined. The problem is that `host_defines.h` unconditionally `#define`s `__forceinline__` which conflicts with the prior `#define` in your link.

Thank you Robert that does work. Seems we will need to find a way to name our files in such a way that builds on both gcc and nvcc.

Comment: @Matt You can use the `-x` option with most compilers to explicitly set the language (e.g. `nvcc -x cu test.cpp` or `gcc -x cpp test.cu`). I believe this can also be controlled using target / source-file properties in CMake if you're using that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: please prefer Jake's solution below. Thanks!**

Add `#include <cuda_runtime.h>` before including thrust headers in order to address your issue. Example:

```
$ cat test.cc
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

int main() { return 0; }
$ g++ -std=c++17 test.cc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Werror
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Sorry to disagree but yours is still the better answer.

Answer (score 4):

Anis' answer is a good option for a short-term workaround.

The other option would be to do `#undef __forceinline__` between the includes:

```
    #include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
    #undef __forceinline__
    #include <cuda_runtime.h>
    
    int main() { return 0; }
```

Also note that the root cause of this issue has already been address in libcudacxx here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/libcudacxx/pull/476

This will ship with the next 2.2 release of Thrust/libcudacxx.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help w/ Cuda 12.1. The problem is that `thrust/execution_policy.h` alone includes conflicting `#define __forceinline__` lines as shown in the question.